# LIKE in SQL work incorrectly?

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, ejb

In my ejb-jar.xml

```
       <query>
            <query-method>
                <method-name>findByCaName</method-name>
                <method-params>
                    <method-param>java.lang.String</method-param>
                </method-params>
            </query-method>
            <ejb-ql>SELECT OBJECT(c) FROM Categories AS c WHERE c.caName LIKE ?1</ejb-ql>
        </query>
```

When I searched, for examples, "Action" , the result is correct, but when I tried finding "Acti", it returned a null collection, can anybody tell me where I were wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You need `LIKE "Acti%"` to search for text that starts with "Acti".

Answer (score 3):

Usually you have to specify wildcards in your like string, such as "Acti%" or "%cti%"

Comment: but because I use parameter, thus I don't know how to do like that

Comment: Did you try to add the '%' to your parameter ?

Comment: yes, but it will cause "Deploy failed" when I tried deploying my application, it doesn't accept '%'

Comment: Are you passing "Acti%" into the findByCaName method?  That shouldn't cause a deployment error if it was deploying before.

Comment: i'm using parameter ?1 (first parameter) so it's impossible to do that

Comment: I mean in the code that calls the method.  Before you probably had a call like 'findByCaName("Action")', which should now be 'findByCaName("Acti%")'

Answer (score 1):

How about appending a % to your parameter:

```
CONCAT(?1, '%')
```

Comment: it deployed but it didn't run :(

Answer (score 0):

Let your parameter be a string and then append `'%' or '_'` as prefix or suffix. '_' refers for a single character variation, and '%' stands for multiple character variation.

But the coolest way is to let user[in a searching functionality] to enter % or _ in and then pass it to query. This gives a huge advantage and flexibility.